# Writing to single file from mappers

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am working on mapreduce that is generating CSV file out of some data that is read from HBase. Is there a way to write to single file from mappers without reduce phase (or to merge multiple files generated by mappers at the end of job)? I know that I can set output format to write in file on Job level, is it possible to do similar thing for mappers?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible (and not uncommon) to have a Map/Reduce-Job without a reduce phase ([example](http://www.lexemetech.com/2008/03/mapreduce-without-reduce.html)). For that you just use `job.setNumReduceTasks(0)`.

However I am not sure how Job-Output is handled in this case. Ususally you get one result file per reducer. Without reducers I could imagine that you either get one file per mapper or that you cannot produce job output. You will have to try/research that.

If the above does not work for you, you could still use the default Reducer implementation, that just forwards the mapper output (identity function).

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. This helped me. Well if we don't specify job.setNumReduceTasks(0), files are named like part-m-00000 etc. If we have default reducer they are named as part-r-0000 etc. I was just wondering if it is possible to merge reducer part files at end of job.

Comment: I figured out that FileUtil.copyMerge(fs, new Path(fileName), fs, new Path(fileName), true, conf, ""); can be used for merging files on job completion

Answer (score 0):

Seriously, this is not how MapReduce works.

Why do you even need a Job for that? Write a simple Java application that does the same for you. There are also command line utils that does the same for you.

Comment: Hi, well I don't agree with this in this particular situation. In this case I may have very large number of records in hbase to process, and doing it in undistributed manner could be a problem. Most simple way to write distributed application is using Map Reduce.